# Route 53 Primary DNS Host Name: Primary DNS IP Address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I recently bought a domain name.

I want to use the domain to route it to my shopify store. So inside of Route 53 I create A record and CNAME. However, my domain provider is asking for Primary and Secondary IP and Hostname.

What should I provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

Once you create the  hosted zone for your domain in Route 53, AWS assigns you name servers:

"Q. How do I get started with Amazon Route 53?
Your hosted zone will be initially populated with a basic set of DNS records, including four virtual name servers that will answer queries for your domain. "

They will look something like this:

- ns-85.awsdns-10.com.
- ns-1686.awsdns-18.co.uk.
- ns-1200.awsdns-22.org.
- ns-956.awsdns-55.net.

The ones **shown in your hosted zone** (not the ones I list above!) are the name servers that the domain registrar wants.

Exactly how you enter these is different for each domain seller, but you can ask their support or look it up in their knowledge base.

If your domain reseller forces you to enter IP addresses, you can get them using "ping" command.  In Windows you would open a command box and type (for example):

ping ns-85.awsdns-10.com

Again, use the names shown in your hosted zone.

Comment: Awesome, Dave! Thank you